# How to install MSBuild tools on Win 10 32-bit machine without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have two machines:
- dev machine --> Win 10 64-bit with Visual Studio 2015
- test machine --> Win 10 32-bit machine without Visual Studio (no version is available)

I have developed DB & Web API apps on 64-bit machine and would like to compile those projects on 32-bit machine.

I have installed Win 10 SDK and also VS 2015 build tools but after those installations, 32-bit machine doesn't have following:
Program Files\MSBuild\Visual Studio

Without those, I can't run my batch files to compile those projects. Any idea how do I get those MSBuild related files? (in my 64-bit machine, I can see SSDT & WebApplications folders which are necessary for compiling DB & Web API projects and I need same on another machine.)

Comment: Separate installer for MSBuild can be easily found at Microsoft Downloads site.

Comment: Hi, at least with TFS2015 and the new build definition you must install Visual Studio 2015 in the build machine. Then you need to configure your project to use "Multi-configuration" in order to compile in x86 and x64 versions

Comment: @LexLi - could you please let me know the link for separate MSBuild installer downloader?

Comment: @ssanga - we are using free TFS online that comes with MSDN account. We can't have VS on the target machine and hence I am looking at other possibilities

Comment: Hello downVoter - reason please?

Answer (score 0):

First off, Visual Studio (VS), SSDT, and MSBuild are separate but related applications. VS installers don't so much install just VS but the typical VS suite of apps which includes MSBuild for most flavors.

If you're setting up a 'build machine' and want to manually shoot over builds to MSBuild, you can use this Microsoft Build Tools 2015 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

However, if you're getting a continuous integration set-up up and going, there are a bunch of options and services. visualstudio.com has some options.

I personally like TeamCity (Subversion, Test & Build)  + Octopus Deploy (pushes builds to the right environment).

Team City can be set-up for a variety of version control and build runners. The free/intro version is full-featured. Octopus' intro version will work for small teams. Both products are well-supported and documented.

Comment: Yes, I understand they are different. I mentioned those items because those are the target tools I need on the build machine. As I mentioned in my question, I have already installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015 but of no use. When I installed it, I see a folder 14.0 under Program Files\MSBuild but that doesn't contain SSDT & Webapplications directories. Note: my target 32-bit machine is not a build machine but QA machine. Testers simply take the source and run batch files to compile. Earlier I have used, Jenkins but now we don't have that luxury. So, I am looking at simplified process.